# How to make prepend and append not clone

Tags: jquery, append, prepend

So I'm moving one element to another element using either prepend or append in some cases such as this:

```
$('.categories').prependTo($('.date'));
```

Now I understand that prepend and append can sometimes clone the content, but how can I cancel that cloning? I can't rename my divs nor create new ones...I simply don't have access.

Comment: Post the webpage with the problem.

Comment: https://stupidproblem.squarespace.com/blog/

Answer (score 1):

Cloning only occurs if there are multiple targets, since this is not true in your case no cloning will occur.

Comment: But it does... http://imageshack.us/a/img214/9722/20120915103423pm.png It will just keep on cloning and I simply can't have this happen....

Comment: @Nick do you have multiple elements with the `date` class?

Comment: @Nick then select only the element which you want `.categories` to be prepended to.

Comment: I am but its still being clone there has to be a way on to cancel the dam cloning if there are classes name the same..... https://stupidproblem.squarespace.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) method which removes the element from the DOM then prepend / append.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li a").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).parent().closest('ul');
    $(this).parent().detach().prependTo(target);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Cat 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Cat 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Cat 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Cat 4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Cat 5</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Cat 6</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```